# error in sort a linked list alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting

I have `LinkedList` of Strings in which I insert a lot of words. I want to sort the list alphabetically.

I searched the Internet and found `Collections.sort(list);`
but when I tried it I got an error.
This is the code:

```
import java.text.Collator;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     LinkedList<String> s=new LinkedList<String>();

        s.insert("cat");
        s.insert("apple");
        s.insert("desk");
        s.insert("bed");
        s.insert("zebra");
        s.insert("floor");

        Collections.sort(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: [link](http://i47.tinypic.com/c0wn6.jpg)

Comment: you can see in link in above the picture of error

Comment: We need to see the `LinkedList` class to be able to help (at least the declaration and the main methods). It must implement (and behave according to the contract in) the `List` interface in order to use the `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: If you use your own `LinkedList` implementation, then `Collections.sort()` won't be able to work with it unless it implements the `java.util.List<T>` interface.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't imported LinkedList and LinkedList doesn't have an insert method. Try this:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     LinkedList<String> s=new LinkedList<String>();

        s.add("cat");
        s.add("apple");
        s.add("desk");
        s.add("bed");
        s.add("zebra");
        s.add("floor");

        Collections.sort(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP has hinted (on a comment below an answer that has been deleted) that he uses his own `LinkedList` implementation.

Comment: @combinatorics Your answer seems good to me... no way of telling if his implementation extends List, no way of knowing if it's sortable.